# Small Windows alternative to Crypto++ for decoding RSA?

Tags: windows, crypto++

Crypto++ is huge (compiled) and I would like to find an alternative to decode a RSA encoded block.

I'm looking for a solution for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows (only) why not use the Windows CryptoAPI?

Crypto API certainly has the ability to perform RSA encryption/decryption. It also has some logic for encoding and decoding PKCS#7/CMS message formats. It's not clear from your question exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Qt, QCA is a small alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check OpenSSL library for windows (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm). I don't know the actual size increase caused by Crypto++,  the latest OpenSSL dll's size (that you need to deploy along with your application) is around 1.5MB.